# Wiki under GNU Free Documentation License - who is the author?

Tags: licensing, license

I'd like to use code of Cholesky decomposition as shown [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition):

This page licenses all its code under GNU Free Documentation License

My understanding is that to appropriately include it into something I'm building I need to:

```
Include license text,
Include license header in appropriate file that containing this Cholesky decomposition.
```

My problem is who do I list as an author?

---

Notes:

Copyright header starts:

```
Copyright  YEAR  YOUR NAME.

Permission is [...].
```

This page is a wiki-style collection of multiple collaborations. This specific page (page section) was written by many people on many different dates. Clearly I need to specify who has (had?) the copyright as highlighted by this sentence in the license text:

```
Secondarily, this License preserves for the author and publisher a way
to get credit for their work, while not being considered responsible
for modifications made by others.
```

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an answer, but I'd personally use "Community" as the author name. If anyone doesn't like it, they'll let you know - and then you'll know what they specifically prefer.

Comment: @KGIII Would you say that picking this particular license for a wiki is a questionable choice then?

Comment: Not at all. It looks fine. I've got some online stuff with the same license, though I'm the sole author. I'd just credit it to 'community' and probably find a tasteful way to link it to the page in question.